# How can WIF be used with OWIN or ASP.NET to enable "Step-up" authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, wif

Suppose a Web browser, or C# application wants to access a resource.  That resource is a very secure webpage, or WebAPI method.

Prior to making the call above,  authentication & authorization has already been done for lower security API calls.

We now need to verify the user with 2 factor (smartcard, yubikey, etc) authentication, and presumably redirect the user to a webpage that asks for this information.

How would I accomplish this scenario in WIF + OWIN?